# Query to compare all columns from Table A with a single column in Table B

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables says Department and Products. 
Products : product_0,product_1,product_2,product_3,product_4,product_5

Department : Dept_name,Dept_type,Dept_prodID

Now i need to compare all the columns from Products with a single column in Department(Dept_prodID) and get the information from Department(Dept_name,Dept_type) for every Column in Products.

I tried the following code :

```
Select (dept.Dept_name,dept.Dept_type) as D1,
(dept.Dept_name,dept.Dept_type) as D2,
(dept.Dept_name,dept.Dept_type) as D3,
(dept.Dept_name,dept.Dept_type) as D4,
(dept.Dept_name,dept.Dept_type) as D5 
from Department dept, Products prod
where  (prod.prod_5=dept.Dept_prodID or
prod.prod_1=dept.Dept_prodID or      
 prod.prod_2=dept.Dept_prodID or
 prod.prod_3=dept.Dept_prodID or 
prod.prod_4=dept.Dept_prodID   )
```

//This gives me same info in all the columns......how should i compare each column of products tables with dept_prodID column in products table?? Should i use joins/Unions or what ...Please suggest !!

Comment: Can you change your schema? `product_0` through `product_5` columns is a bit of an antipattern in a relational database, a separate table would make more sense. An array column might make sense in certain situations as well but probably not here.

Comment: "Compare" how? Please be more specific. And add proper table difinitions including types and other relevant information - what you get with `\d tbl` in psql. Add some example values and the expected result.

Comment: Columns in product Table are of distinct values but of same typeas column Dept_prodID in department table.